# DUnit test - Cannot create form. No MDI forms are currently active

Tags: delphi-2009, dunit

I'm starting with DUnit tests so sorry in advance for any newbie mistakes. When I tried to run simple tests and the compiler runs the SetUp of my test class, it stops returning the message '**Cannot create form. No MDI forms are currently active**'.

After some research, I found some explanations but none related to my problem.

The problem appears to be when I call the Create method of my child origin class - by origin I mean the class where I have all the procedures and functions to be tested, lets call it by TfrmFoo. And my **test class** should be the TestTfrmFoo. The TFrmFoo has a parent with some basic codes, the TfrmParentFoo.

I'm calling the Create method like this:

```
...

implementation

procedure TestTfrmFoo.SetUp;
begin

    FfrmParentFoo := TfrmParentFoo.Create(nil);

    FfrmFoo := TfrmFoo.Create(FfrmParentFoo);    

end;

procedure TestTfrmFoo.TearDown;
begin
    FfrmFoo.Free;
    FfrmFoo := nil;
end;

...
```

After that, the Create method of the TfrmFoo class is called and the following error occurs: '**Cannot create form. No MDI forms are currently active**'.

I already tried to override the Create of my child class TfrmFoo setting the FormStyle property to 'fsNormal' instead 'fsMDIChild' and nothing. I also found some ideas about using a sleep(500) but the problem continues.

**Edited:**
After the `Remy Lebeau` contribution, I changed the SetUp test to create the parent form before calling the child, and using it as a parameter to the Create child. Same error message. Did I change something wrong?

Any other tips? tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `TForm` has its `FormStyle` set to `fsMDIChild`, the project *MUST* have an `Application.MainForm` created whose `FormStyle` is set to `fsMDIForm`.  This is a **hard-coded requirement of the VCL**, not the underlying MDI system (though, there is a way to [circumvent this limitation](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23574) with some manual work).

The error you are seeing means your project does not have an `Application.MainForm` created and set to `fsMDIForm` before any `fsMDIChild` forms are created.  You need to fix that.

Setting the child form's `FormStyle` in its constructor or `OnCreate` event is too late, because the error happens when the child form creates its HWND, which occurs early in the DFM streaming process, before `Create`/`OnCreate` has an oppurtunity to try assigning the `FormStyle`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The downside is that is necessary to map all references that come with the parent manually in the .dpr file, once isn't done automatically and I could't find a way to map a entire specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I removed only the child Create method
`FfrmFoo := TfrmFoo.Create(FfrmParentFoo);` and worked like a charm :D.

The problem was because I was trying to create a new child instance even after create a parent new one. The final code became like following:

```
...

implementation

procedure TestTfrmFoo.SetUp;
begin

  FfrmParentFoo := TfrmParentFoo.Create(nil);    

end;

procedure TestTfrmFoo.TearDown;
begin
  FfrmFoo.Free;
  FfrmFoo := nil;
end;

...
```

Thanks `Remy Lebeau` for the insight.